# angular access ng-repeat array from child directive

Tags: angularjs

I had an idea for an angular directive but I'm not sure if it's possible.

I often have to delete and item from an ng-repeat array, so the de facto solution is to have a function on the scope:

```
 $scope.remove = function(item) { 
    var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);     
 }
```

I'm constantly writing this boiler plate code for every ng-repeat and it would be nice to be able to do something like this instead:

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button ng-click-remove="item"></button>
 </li>
```

Basically I'm thinking the directive will simply wrap ng-click, but then I start thinking, is it even possible to access the items array from my directive without knowing its name or using $parent?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is create a service handling the deletion/Creation of said task, and then just use that wrapper in the controller. I mean, the way you are suggesting, you still need to write the same code, but just do it in the directive. Also, yes it is possible to access it from the directive, you can pass in the controller to it.

```
function dir() {
 return {
  controller: 'ctrl as ctrl',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){
      console.log(ctrl.items);
      console.log(attrs.ngClickRemove); // gets the value of item.
}
 }
}
```

Though I would caution using the ng syntax since it should be reserved for Angularjs.

Comment: the code you post relies on knowing the name of the array "items". As I mentioned that's not acceptable, and neither is a service to inject into the controller (which defeats the purpose of removing such code from the controller). I'm looking for a possibly esoteric or angular internal method to access "the currently iterating ng-repeat array". If no such method exists, then there is no answer to this question

Comment: You could use the fact that you have attrs.ngClickRemove which will give you the value of item and you have access to the scope so perhaps you could do something there.